# How to use Limits in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDb table `customers`.

In this table I have 20m+ rows of data.

Schema of the table:

- Partition Key - group_id
- Sorting Key - customer_email

I have an attribute called

```
     "assigned_lists": [
        "e9d55940-77da-11e9-9c25-df4d7393de10",
        ...
     ]
```

in this table. The `assigned_lists` is a list datatype of strings. I want that customer who belongs to some `assigned_lists`. Simply I searched for the contains function of the dynamo DB

```
 FilterExpression: "contains(#list, :searchForThisList)"
```

I'm querying on this table with the limit of 100 means I need 100 customers which belong in given `assigned_lists` one customer can be in multiple `assigned_lists` so I use the LIST datatype.

My approach for limit:

Limit : 100,

```
        Dynamo.query(params, (err,data)=>{
          if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
             if (data.Count < params.Limit) { //calculating that we get all the data or not

                    params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                    params.Limit -= data.Count; //Setting the new limit for the next query
                    dynamoDb.query(params, againComeHere);
                    } else {
                       //my process with the data
                    }
        })
```

I have some questions:

**Note:** I'm beginner with dynamoDB

**1.** Have I use a fine logic for limiting? Because it takes more than 2 minutes for generating the results and I need to show it to the front in my website

**2.** Is the dynamoDb is a correct database for me?

I m eager for the responses.

Comment: Please ask me for more clarifications if any confusions

Comment: I am not sure, but given the access pattern you are talking about here, your schema sounds off to me. Why is group_id your partition key if you are trying to see if a customer is in an assigned list. Sounds more like you need to have the customerID as the PK and the assigned_list as another attribute, then use a GSI where the assigned_list is the Partition Key and userID is the Sort Key. Then you can easily and VERY quickly say "get me all of the customers in assigned_list XYZ". The best would be to have a list of your access patterns and some sample data to look at.

Comment: Also, sooner than later go watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k

Comment: Actually, every customer belong in a group and email id is unique in that group